# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[ { propiedad1: x, propiedad2: y } ]" at path "xxxxx"

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Error que me da la consola al querer hacer la petición Post agregando un auto a la colección de autos que se encuentra dentro del modelo de cliente:

> (node:12176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Car validation failed: client: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[ {
> nombre: 'Ford', apellido: 'Fiat' } ]" at path "client"

Modelo auto

```
 const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
    
    let CarSchema = new Schema({
      model: { type: String, required: [true, "the model field is required"] },
      colour: { type: String, required: [true, "the colour field is required"] },
    
      client: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Client",
        required: true
      },
    });
    
    CarSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
      const { __v, ...data } = this.toObject();
      return data;
    };
```

Modelo cliente

```
module.exports = model( 'Car', CarSchema );
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
    
    let ClientSchema = new Schema({
        
        nombre: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'El nombre es obligatorio']
        },
        apellido: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'El correo es obligatorio']
        },
        car: [
                { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'car' ,
                required: [true, 'El auto es obligatorio']
            }],
    });
    
    ClientSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
        const { __v, ...client  } = this.toObject();
        client.id = _id;
        return client;
    }
    
    module.exports = model( 'Client', ClientSchema );
```

ControladorCar

```
let Car = require('../models/car');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    exports.car_create_post = async function(req, res) {
        const car = new Car(req.body);
        delete car._id;
        await car.save();
        
        const client = await Client.findById({_id: car.client})
        client.car.push(car);
        await client.save();
        res.status(200).json({success:true, data: car })
    };
```

Comment: Pues si que puedes (debes) cambiar algunas cosas en tu implementación. En cuanto pueda te doy una respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879729/12788110), estás guardando *el objeto completo* en vez del `ObjectId` de `car`:

```
client.car.push(car);
```

En su lugar, deberías guardar el `ObjectId` del nuevo `car`. Recuperar el objeto nuevo retornado en la función `.save()` podría ser un método para obtener su `_id`:

```
await car.save()
         .then(newCar => {
            const client = await Client.findById({_id: car.client});
            client.car.push(newCar._id); //<--------
            await client.save();
            return res.status(200).json({success:true, data: car });
          });
```

<sub><sup>(asumiendo que te encargarás de validar los errores con un try-catch, por ejemplo) :)</sup></sub>

Comment: yo quiero guardar el objeto completo dentro del array, como seria eso?

Comment: En ese caso, estarías _rompiendo_ lo que definiste en el schema de `Client`. Por cierto, en `ClientSchema.car` estás referenciando al modelo en minúscula: es decir: `ref: 'car'`, cuando debería ser `ref: 'Car'`.